# NetworkStream.Read delay .Net

Tags: .net, sockets, tcpclient, networkstream

I have a class that inherits from TcpClient. In that class I have a method to process responses. In that method I call I get the NetworkStream with MyBase.GetStream and call Read on it.

This works fine, excpet the first call to read blocks too long. And by too long I mean that the socket has recieved plenty of data, but won't read it until some arbitrary limit is reached. I can see that it has recieved plenty of data using the packet sniffer WireShark.

I have set the recieve buffer to small amounts, and very small amounts (like just a few bytes) to no avail. I have done the same with the buffer byte array I pass to the read method, and it still delays.

Or to put it another way. I am download 600k. The download takes 5 seconds (at a little over 100k/second connection to the server which makes sense). The initial Read call takes 2-3 seconds and tells me only 256 bytes are availble (256 is the Recieve buffer and the size of the array I read in to). Then magically, the other few hundred thousand bytes can be read in 256 byte chunks in only a few process ticks each. Using a packet sniffer, I know that during those initial 2-3 seconds, the socket has recieved much more than just 256 bytes. My connection wasn't .25k/second for 3 seconds and then 400k for 2 seconds.

How do I get the bytes from a socket as they come in?

Comment: What else sits between your NIC and your app?  Disable firewall, virus scanner, CRL, proxy, see what happens.

Comment: nobugz, that was the issue. It was my anti-virus app. It must be buffering a certain amount of bytes to scan them before it feeds it to the socket buffer.

Which makes sense because I am using a well known port that it would scan. I cannot believe I did not think about that.

You should post that as an answer so I can mark it as good.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when writing an open source [C# network library](http://www.networkcomms.net/c-network-library/). Try setting:

```
tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
tcpClient.Client.NoDelay = true;
```

This disables the [nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) operating by default. This causes all sorts of random delays, deliberately, when sending and receiving very small amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this a few times before too, and it seems to have to do with checking up on the machine's Internet Explorer settings (proxy settings/LAN settings etc etc) which caused the 2-3 seconds delay.

Classes inside the System.Net namespace (i.e. WebClient, HttpWebRequest) seems to do this automatically on the first request.

You can try turning off or changing IE's proxy settings/LAN settings particularly the automatic settings detection option, it may help.

If that doesn't help, take a look at this article: [Mysterious delay on first use of HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/topic42525.aspx). It's not exactly the TcpClient but I think it's the same problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was a good idea. But I disabled detecting proxies, in IE and in app.config, and it did not affect the delay.